# Lock a row in MySQL to prevent dirty reads?

Tags: java, mysql, locking

Is there any way to explicitly lock a row in a table? I have some application logic I need to run on a row, which looks like the following (java):

```
Connection conn = ...;
try {
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);

    Game game = selectStatement(conn, gameId);

    doLongRunningWorkOnGameObject(game);

    updateStatement(conn, game);

    conn.commit();
}
...
```

So, if multiple users enter into this code block at roughly the same time, they could have various dirty states of the Game row that they are working on. I would like to lock the row completely, forcing other users to wait (even to read it) in this case.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395932/prevent-read-when-updating-the-table

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can use SET TRANSACTION. Set the transaction prior to each game row change, you then have an exclusive lock on the row. Update the game row, then commit the transaction to release the lock, then move to the next users turn. Something like:

```
updateStatement(conn, game) {
    START TRANSACTION GAME_MOVE;   
    ... code to do the move...
    COMMIT TRANSACTION GAME_MOVE;
}
```

[MySQL SET TRANSACTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)